# Как вынести подключение к БД в конфиг?

Tags: c++, база-данных, qt, postgresql, config

У меня есть db.conf:

```
{
  "dbname" : "ObservationLog",
  "dbhost" : "127.0.0.1",
  "dbport" : 5432,
  "dbuser" : "postgres",
  "dbpassword" : "truf",
  "encoding" : "UTF8",
  "timeout"  : 1
}
```

В папке conf/db.conf . Я в .pro его подключаю так :`include( conf/db.conf )`. Но в папке с компилируемой программой этот файл не создаётся. Как в Qt выносят подключения к БД в конфиг ?

Comment: самое простое - ручками скопировать

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `DISTFILES` хранит файлы, которые должны быть скопированы в целевую директорию:

```
DISTFILES += <filename>
```

[Документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#distfiles). Но это решение работает только в ОС основанных на Unix (Mac OS, Linux).

---

Есть универсальное решение: создать кастомный этап сборки, в нём прописать консольные команды для каждой ОС.

1. Кликните иконку **"Projects"** в боковом меню;
2. Там есть **"Build Steps"** в разделе **"Build Settings"**;
3. Кликните кнопку **"Add Build Step"**;
4. Выделите **"Custom build step"**;
5. В поле **"Commands"** введите Ваши команды, без аргументов;
6. В поле **"Arguments"** введите команды (например, `%{sourceDir}/YourFile %{buildDir}`);
7. Идите назад в **"Edit"** и попробуйте собрать проект.

[Источник](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38875/how-do-i-get-a-text-file-to-copy-into-a-build/8).

Comment: А можно по подробней, что в поле "Commands" писать или указывать? Чтоб в скомпилированной версии  появился файл conf/db.conf

Comment: @IvanTriumphov команду для копирования файла Вашей операционной системы. Вероятно это Windows, я с ним не работаю, поэтому здесь поможет Гугл. Суть в том, что при вызове к этой команде добавятся аргументы, определённые в `Arguments`. Там можно использовать переменные вида `%{}` для использования директории исходников и целевой.